# Regular Expressions - Replacing Using Backreferences

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace a pattern using sed.  I want to do a global search and replace
in which I replace the pattern `~~\d{3}~~` with `A\d{3}\B`. In other words, I want to 
replace `~~345~~` with `A345B`.

My file (src.txt) contains one line:

`hello ~~123~~ hello ~~12~~ hello ~~456~~ hello`

I want to change this to:

`hello A123B hello ~~12~~ hello A456B hello`

I tried this on the command line:

`sed -i -c "s/~~(\d{3})~~/A\\1B/g" src.txt`

However, nothing is changed.  What am I doing wrong?

P.S. - Eventually I would like to do this kind of replacement
in a Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{3})
```

Try this in javascript.Replace by `A$1B`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/31

Comment: Thank you very much!  The tool on regex101.com is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, it's pretty simple:

```
var string = 'hello ~~123~~ hello ~~12~~ hello ~~456~~ hello',
    regex =/~~(\d{3})~~/g;

string = string.replace(regex, 'A$1B');
console.log(string); // hello A123B hello ~~12~~ hello A456B hello
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam.  I'm curious about how you would do it on the command line using sed.  Any thoughts?